# Django -- One Template used with multiple variables

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to display a list of tickets in an HTML table. The table has various headings to display various aspects of the tickets. I would like to present this same table in a bunch of different locations across my project.

I've made a single template of `/templates/shared/ticket_list.html` in which presents the ticket list and then I `{% include %}` it where I need to display this listing. Simple enough.

However, there are a couple of pages in my project where I have a Bootstrap [tabbed](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) div. I want to display this table of tickets in *both* tabs, but with a different set of tickets. The HTML for this essentially requires that I `{% include %}` my table template twice on the same HTML page.

For example:

- Tab 1: "Created By User" -- a list of tickets that the current user created
- Tab 2: "Assigned To User" -- a list of tickets that are assigned to the current user

In the view, I might have something like:

```
created_by_ticks = Ticket.objects.filter(created_by = self.request.user)
assigned_to_ticks = Ticket.objects.filter(assigned_to = self.request.user)
```

The problem is, in my ticket table template, how would I present both querysets since the table itself is likely expecting a single variable name, such as:

```
{% for t in tickets %}
<tr>...

{% endfor %}
```

But passing in two querysets of tickets, I now have two ticket variables of `created_by_ticks` and `assigned_to_ticks`.

Any ideas how I could use that single ticket table template, but use multiple variables, or some other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `with` functionality of the include tag:

```
{% include 'shared/ticket_list.html' with tickets=created_by_ticks %}
{% include 'shared/ticket_list.html' with tickets=assigned_to_ticks %}
```

Comment: Nice! I figured there'd be a simple solution that I hadn't thought of. I'll give this a go. Thanks